# SIM Toolkit keeps disappearing from app drawer

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I purchased a phone sometime back (LG G3) that initially came with Android Kitkat. Eveyrything worked beautifully until I upgraded to Lollipop. Many things suddenly broke but my main concern is the SIM toolkit disappears a few minutes after reboot. I use the toolkit a lot and it's a pain to have to reboot the phone twice or thrice a day.
Can this be fixed or the phone is now forever broken?

Comment: Have you tried factory data reset? It seems to resolve a lot of issues after the update. Just remember to backup your data beforehand ;)

Comment: Yes. I have reset it twice. That helped with speed as it was quite slow. It did not help with other problems. Thanks for suggesting though.